# What does "mushy" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is the context from [Joel Spolsky's blog](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/08/01.html):

> And now I'm going to get a little bit **mushy**, and argue that the most
>   productive programming environments are the ones that let you work at
>   different levels of abstraction.

The meaning of *mushy* as in [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/mush?q=mushy) doesn't quite fit in here. What does *mushy* mean?

Comment: Try [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mushy), meaning 2; I think that'll answer your question. (+1 for providing context and research, complete with links.)

Comment: @J.R. yes it does .

Comment: I like [Merriam-Webster 1b](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mushy) better. He's descending from  rigorous, precise, code-level discussion to something vaguer, fuzzier, soft around the edges.

Comment: @StoneyB: Nice find. I, too, like that one even better.

Comment: @J.R.  The best dictionary is the one which confirms your prior opinion!

Comment: @Will: Actually, I think here it means *my (soft) personal opinion, and not hard scientific fact*. But it is indeed a metaphor along the same lines as the *too emotional* dictionary meaning.

Comment: @Will I would put it more pointedly (less mushily?) than PeterShor: I don't find the Spolsky quote emotional at all. The answer from T.E.D. and the comment from StoneyB are much more applicable here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a term used to indicate that, while the preceeding arguments were as objective and well-supported as he could make them ("hard" or "firm"), what follows is more subjective.